# making an option >reserved< with boolean?

Tags: java, netbeans

Alright so, i got my programm "finished" up to the point where i cant solve this simple problem.

i got this:

```
package hotel;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
*
* @author Defalt
*/
public class Hotel {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Prices prices = new Prices();
    Scanner user_in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String method;
    boolean taken = false;
    boolean taken2 = false;
    boolean taken3 = false;
    boolean again = true;

    //***********Introduction to the hotel*************

    System.out.println("Welcome to Hotel Vermond's Heaven!");
    System.out.println("We are happy to see that you would like to stay with us.");

    //***********Creating of a Loop*************


    do {
    System.out.println("Please, type which room you would like to book: ");
    System.out.println("Single Bed, Double Bed, President Suit");
    method = user_in.nextLine();

    //***********Choices of Rooms and Question to book another one*************

    if ("Single Bed".equals(method)) {
            System.out.println(prices.describe1());
    if ("y".equals(user_in.nextLine())){
         if(taken=true){
                System.out.println("We are sorry, this room is already booked. Please choose another one");
            }else again=true;
    } else again=true;
        } else if ("Double Bed".equals(method)){
            System.out.println(prices.describe2());
    if ("y".equals(user_in.nextLine())){
            taken2 = true;
            again=true;
        } else again=true;
    } else if ("President Suit".equals(method)){
            System.out.println(prices.describe3());
    if ("y".equals(user_in.nextLine())){
            taken3 = true;
            again=true;
    } else again=true;

    } else {
            System.out.println("Please choose one of the rooms above.");
    }
            System.out.println("Would you like to book another Room(y/n)\n");

    //***********Outbreak if User declines another booking*************
    //***********Otherwise redo the whole process************* 

    if ("y".equals(user_in.nextLine())){
        again=true;
    } else{
        break;
    }
 }while(again);
    System.out.println("Thank you and goodbye!");

   }
}
```

and my other class is this:

```
package hotel;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
*
* @author Defalt
*/
public class Prices {
Scanner user_in = new Scanner(System.in);
int price1 = 300;
int price2 = 800;
int price3 = 2500;

//***********Information of the Room including Validation Question*************

public String describe1() {  
       return
        "You Choose the Single Bed.\n\tThis room Contains 1 Bed, 1 Fridge a Bathroom but no View on the Ocean.\n\tThis room will cost CHF " + price1 + ".-.\n\tWould you like to book this room?(y/n)";
   }
public String describe2() {  
   return
    "You Choose the Double Bed.\n\tThis room Contains 1 Queen-size Bed, 1 Fridge a bathroom, an Icemaker but no View on the Ocean.\n\tThis room will cost CHF " + price2 + ".-.\n\tWould you like to book this room?(y/n)";
   } 
public String describe3() {  
   return
    "You Choose the President Suit.\n\tThis room Contains 1 King-size Bed, 1 Fridge, XXL Bathroom, Private Entertainment-System, 65inch Flatscreen and a Balcony with View on the Ocean.\n\tThis room will cost CHF " + price3 + ".-.\n\tWould you like to book this room?(y/n)";
   } 
}
```

As you can see i tried to make the `Single Bed` a reserved room after it has been taken. Yet the `System.out.println("We are sorry, this room is already booked. Please choose another one");` is shown even on the first booking.

why is that eventhough the initial value of my `taken` boolean is false?
what other option are there that i could take to make my idea work?

PS!: I think i got it working the first time BUT it kept the taken value on true no matter how often i close the program and restart it. (just a side note)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
if(taken=true){
            System.out.println("We are sorry, this room is already booked. Please choose another one");
```

to

```
if(taken==true){
            System.out.println("We are sorry, this room is already booked. Please choose another one");
```

Note the double equals in the if condition. This will check the value of `taken` instead of just always setting it to `true`, which is what is currently happening.

Alternatively, since `taken` is already a boolean value, you can simplify it to this:

```
if(taken){
            System.out.println("We are sorry, this room is already booked. Please choose another one");
```

It would probably help you to catch these problems if you fixed your formatting and indentation. I tend to avoid omitting the curly braces at any time. This is generally java standard formatting:

```
if(condition) {
    if(condition) {
        // do the thing
    }
    else {
        // do the other thing
    }
}
else if(condition) {
    // do another thing
}
else {
    // do the third thing
}
```

Notice how ifs/else ifs/elses at the same nesting level are also kept at the same indentation level. This helps a lot with keeping them straight.

**Edit:**

Another thing I would like to point out is that you have the `again` boolean but you aren't using it. Instead of `break`ing out of the loop if the user is finished, use the `again` boolean you have like you should be and set it false. That will cause the loop condition to fail and exit the loop nicely. Using break is ugly.

Comment: ah yes. have to work my formating i admit that. exactly the ==.... such simple mistake. thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Happens to the best of us!

Comment: true i just corrected what u said, i even did `taken=true;`after the `System.out.println` but it doesnt correct it when i select the single bed again. as if the condition isnt met and the boolean didnt change. any ideas?

`("Single Bed".equals(method)) {
                System.out.println(prices.describe1());
        if ("y".equals(user_in.nextLine())){
             if(taken==true){
                    System.out.println("We are sorry, this room is already booked. Please choose another one");
                    taken=true;
                }else again=true;`

Comment: You need to put `taken=true;` in the case where the user typed `y` and the room _wasn't_ taken, just like you have for "Double Bed" and "President Suit" where you set `taken2 = true;` and `taken3 = true;`

Comment: That is what i do, yet it doesnt change the boolean. If i put it after the `y` and before the `if(taken)` then it will show me that it is taken on the first run (which it shouldnt as it should do it on the second run) if i do `taken=true;`after the `ìf(taken)` then nothing happens as if the whole boolean isnt present.

Comment: Putting it inside `if(taken)` is the case where the room **was** taken. You need to set `taken=true;` in the case where the room **was not** taken, which means you want it in the `else` part _after_ `if(taken)`

Comment: last comment. it worked understood now why i have to put it into the else function. thanks a lot for your patience you really helped me out here!

Comment: It was my pleasure. Friendly reminder to accept my answer if you would be so kind? :)